# Access variables from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get a variable `currentID` from `renderermain.js` and use it in `renderermem.js`.

However, I need to do this **without** having to add this to `mem.html`:

```js
<script src="renderermain.js"></script>
<script src="renderermem.js"></script>
```

Because I cannot mix these two.

I have tried:

**renderermain.js**

```js
globalVariable={currentID:activeID};
```

**renderermem.js**

```js
var currentID = globalVariable.currentID;
```

But this doesn't work.

**Note:** I am switching html files at this point from `main.html` (using `renderermain.js`) to `mem.html` (using `renderermem.js`).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: [this doesn't work is not a helpful statement](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What happens? What errors are reported? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I am switching html files at this point"...ok so that's two separate pages being loaded in your browser. When the browser moves to a new page, everything that was in the previous one is destroyed. So any Javascript that was running there no longer exists.

Comment: If you want to pass a variable from one page to another, you need to include it on the querystring of the URL (of the new page)

Comment: Or cookies, or session/local storage, indexed DB, etc.

Comment: @Jacob I always forget about those, thanks. Something like localstorage is probably a better idea than faffing about with querystrings, if the variable isn't needed server-side (which it seems it isn't, from the description).

Comment: localStorage worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are two ways to pass variables between web pages. The first method is to use sessionStorage, or localStorage. The second method is to use a query string with the URL.

To use sessionStorage or localStorage:
This goes in the first web page:

```
// "myVariable" is the sessionStorage variable name
// "variable_one" is the variable string value

sessionStorage.setItem("myVariable", "variable_one);

// This goes in the second web page:
// Retrieve the sessionStorage variable
var myVariable = sessionStorage.getItem('myVariable');
```

Query String with URL:
Pass a string as a parameter.

Example:

```
<a href="filename.html?data1|data2|data3">Go to filename</a>
```

When Go to filename is clicked, filename.html is loaded with the query string

```
"?data1|data2|data3"
```

appended to the filename in the address bar. To get the query string into variables,
use:

```
var queryString = location.search.substring(1);
```

The variable queryString now has the value

```
"data1|data2|data3"
```

To break these out into individual variables use split:

```
var a = queryString.split("|"); 
// which creates an array
```

Then get the values out of the array and put them into variables:

```
var value1 = a[0];
var value2 = a[1];
var value3 = a[2];
```

Now:

```
value1 == "data1", value2 == "data2", value3 == "data3"
```

Comment: The _Third_ way is by setting a cookie with the value; the _Fourth_ way is by `POST`ing it (possibly via AJAX / JSON) to the server to store in a server-maintained session.